# Python - How to fix CWE-117: Improper Output Neutralization for Logs

Tags: python, esapi, veracode

I have tried using  clean = message.replace('\n', '*').replace('\r', '*').
But it still fails the veracode scan.
Is there any better way to do it?
Also I read about ESAPI Python but not getting any good documentation to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ESAPI Python unfortunately is an extremely long dead project.  I don't have any Python alternatives, but the library hasn't had a commit since [August 9, 2010.](https://code.google.com/archive/p/owasp-esapi-python/source/default/commits)

I'm not familiar with Python web frameworks, but I *do* teach regularly about secure programming.

Every time you make a function call, you need to ask yourself the question:

"Am I passing this off of to an interpreter?"

If the answer is "yes," then you need to encode to ensure that THAT function is going to treat the input purely as data and not executable code.

In this particular case, if your logging has the potential to be interpreted by a browser (which is common) you'd also want to encode for HTML.  However if your environment *never* uses html-based logging and is always raw text, this could be considered "mitigated" or a "false positive" depending on how your company has agreed to those terms.

Also, I like the practice of wrapping any user input with a unique delimiter. You can use square brackets, but I like strong visual cues in my logs.

Picture: [USERACTION] + userId + ' ►' + encode(userInput) + '◀'

Or even:

[USERACTION] + userId + ' ( ͡ʘ ͜ʖ ͡ʘ)' + encode(userInput) + '<:::::[]=¤ (▀̿̿Ĺ̯̿̿▀̿ ̿)'

Anything that helps make it obvious that someone has tampered with your logs is good.  The louder the better!